# Having Issues with Components Not Rendering or Re-Rendering Too Many Times on State Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're working on an inventory management page of sorts. The page makes a call to an external API and if that endpoint returns data, it displays that data on the page for the user. The API call uses the current logged in users ID, so we use `userLoaded` to wait for that ID before making the API call.

If an inventory doesn't exist (API returns nothing), we show some "Not Available" text.

However, when a page initially loads, it's showing the "Not Available" text, re-rendering a couple times, and then finally showing the correct data. Is there anyway to cut back on those re-renders or make it more graceful?

You can see the issue here: https://recordit.co/EYDLupg3xs or on the demo link here: https://showzone.io/inventory

Oddly enough, the table component is not re-rendering with the data - so it stays blank. But if you force the table to re-render (by using one of the Filters for example), the data does indeed show. How can we re-render the table component when the data is ready?

Here is the code (cut down a bit to make it easier to understand):

```
function Inventory() {
  const { currentUser, userLoaded } = useAuth()
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const [inventoryExists, setInventoryExists] = useState(false)

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    if (userLoaded) {
        const userInventoryData = await axios.get(
          `https://showzone-api.herokuapp.com/api/user-inventory/${currentUser.uid}` // For the demo link, I hardcoded a value for testing purposes 
        )
        setData(userInventoryData.data)
        setInventoryExists(true)
    }
  }, [currentUser?.uid, userLoaded])

  useEffect(fetchData, [fetchData])

  return (
    <>
     .....
      <TabPanel value="1" sx={{ padding: 0 }}>
        <Card mb={6}>
          <CardContent>
            <Grid container spacing={6}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <Typography>
                  <strong>Total Cards: </strong>{" "}
                  {inventoryExists
                    ? data?.owned_count?.toLocaleString() +
                      " / " +
                      data?.total_card_count?.toLocaleString()
                    : "Not Available"}
                </Typography>
                <Typography>
                  <strong>Estimated Value: </strong>{" "}
                  {inventoryExists
                    ? data?.owned_value?.toLocaleString()
                    : "Not Available"}
                </Typography>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6} sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {inventoryExists ? (
                  <div>
                    <Doughnut
                      data={{
                        datasets: [
                          {
                            data: [
                              Math.round(data?.owned_count),
                              Math.round(data?.total_card_count),
                            ],
                          },
                        ],
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <BlankDoughnut text="Cards" />
                )}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </TabPanel>
      <Divider />
      {inventoryExists ? (
        <PlayerSearch id={currentUser?.uid} />
      ) : (
        <PlayerSearch />
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a Loading or Fetching state that is initialized to `true` to display some UI or loader while the data is being fetched? That way you could achieve a better effect / experience.

Comment: Expanding on @ivanatias comment, I guess MUI Skeleton can help you with that: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-skeleton/